# Convertir fechas en Laravel

Tags: laravel, carbon

Tengo que leer de una bd un registro que no guardo yo, lo guarda otra persona.
y debo saber si el dia de "HOY" o un dia en especifico, existe un registro.

Uso laravel 8, y estuve intentando con today() pero no es el formato adecuado.

La fecha en la bd, se guarda asi:

> 2021-04-14 12:36:04

si yo le digo a eloquent que me busque donde el campo fecha sea igual a today():

today() tiene este formato:

> "2021-04-15T00:00:00.000000Z"

Como son formatos distintos claramente no encuentra un registro.
como podria convertir el dato que esta en la bd a un formato de solo  año mes dia, para yo poder buscar un registro de un dia en especifico, si busco con now(), tampoco va a encontrar nada, ya que este la parte de minutos y segundos no va a ser igual.

quiero hacer una consulta tipo asi, pero no me funciona:

```
$registros = Users::where('fecha', now())->get();
```

Este me trae un array vacio, porque no encuentra un registro donde la fecha sea igual a:

> now() = "2021-04-15T19:39:30.776983Z"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes usar

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Para obtener la fecha, para lo cual si quieres registros de hoy

```
Model::whereDay('created_at', date('d'))->get();//dia de Hoy
Model::whereDay('created_at', '25')->get();//dia 25
```

También puedes probar

```
Model::whereDate
Model::whereMonth
Model::whereYear
Model::whereTime
```

Comment: No hay necesidad de usar la función date(), con `now()->day` obtenemos el número del día y seguimos con el uso de Carbon

Answer (score 0):

@manrrique meneses yaranga, gracias me sirvio tu respuesta:

para sacar solo el año mes y dia de una fecha usé la opcion que me mostraste de:

```
Model::whereDate
```

y finalmente me quedó la contulta asi:

```
$registros = Users::whereDate('fecha', now()->format('Y-m-d'))->get();
```

en principio queria solo el dia, pero ya viendo las opciones, me animé para no generar errores y pasarle tambien el mes, y luego me animé a pasar el año, asi no tendria ninguna duda.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: También puedes hacerlo así: `now()->toDateString();`